# Hacks for improving performance on large scenes

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, performance, hardware, optimization

Hi I’m using blender mostly doing exterior architecture visualisations. Through previous months I’ve found many problems that affects this software. But the main issue is lack of performance power when doing large scenes.

Situation looks like this.
I’ve got large scene: 6GB file size 6 042 836 faces and everything goes really slow (Modeling, applying and creating shaders). After redefining any geometry or moving object Blender gives me this blue loading circle for at least 30 seconds and sometimes even 2 minutes
Scene must include many objects like main building, surroundings, people, cars, foliage and so on.

Everything is put on separate collections ,and hiding them helps a lot. But this is not enough everything is still very slow. My texture size varies between 1-4k. I’ve also tried using alt-d when making duplicates but it is still not enough
I was wondering what are the best options to improve my workflow and above all speed of modeling.

I’ve thought about buying new CPU but until modeling in blender is not multithread process I think this won’t help

Below I put my main questions:

What are your best hacks for improving performance on large scenes?

What is the best CPU for faster modelling on large scenes like mine?

Can I improve anything on Hardware side to make my scene work faster ?

What consumes most performance on scenes like mine ?

Last thing my stats:
CPU Intel® Core™ i9-7900X CPU @ 3.30GHz
GPU NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2080 Ti
64 GB RAM

Comment: This (now historical) post is too broad for BSE. To be answerable here, it should contain , substantially, one question only.